# sencha cordova android apk size getting increased every build

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, sencha-architect, android-build

My problem is that sencha cordova android is increasing the size of my apk file every time I build it.  I am not added any files to the project, but even so the size increases

- My apk Size at first build - 4.5MB
- After some 10+ Build (No change in files)  - 10.5MB
- After some 50+ Build (No change in files)  - 30.5MB

I have tried running `cordova clean` but it makes little difference.  How do I solve this?

Comment: thanks for the edit @stephen c

Comment: Please extract both the apk at first build and the apk at last build with your prefered UNZIP program into new folders and compare the contents. Which files are bigger; which files are added over time?

Comment: It could be caused by the generated CSS files, try to delete them and regenerate again.